# Write data into .txt file created by CFileDialog, in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I wanna Write data into .txt file created by CFileDialog, in C++.

The problem I am facing is that below codes doesn't work, although there is no build error. The .txt file created by CFileDialog can not be found for some reason. What's wrong the code?

what's the efficient way to Write data into .txt file created by CFileDialog, in C++?

Thanks

```
CFileDialog dlg(FALSE, NULL, NULL, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
    _T("My Data File (*.txt)|*.txt||"));
if(dlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
     return;
CString filename = dlg.GetPathName();
ofstream outfile (filename);
int mydata = 10;
outfile << "my data:" << mydata << endl;
outfile.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, it'll help you format your questions properly.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the mess. I will follow the suggested format.

Comment: Did you try to debug, what is there in the "filename" variable?

Comment: It is the full path of the test.txt file generated by the CFileDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use ofstream when you using MFC? You could use a CFile isn't it? Any specific reason why you are using ofstream?

Comment: There's no rule saying you have to use MFC exclusively. Personally I like to use C++ standards where possible, and MFC specific stuff only where it makes more sense. For example I stopped using CArray years ago.

Comment: Yes, it looks really ugly to mix MFC with Ofstream. You are right, I can use CFile. The only reason I try Ofstream is it looks simple. Well, it is not a good idea.

Comment: Is there any equivalent part to CFileDialog in standard C++? Thanks

Comment: @younevertell, standard C++ doesn't include *any* GUI capabilites. So the answer is no.

Comment: Mark..there is a function called GetopenFileName which is a win32 function which almost equivalent to CFileDialog...is that right?

Comment: I did not notice the question was "Can someone ask me why I use ofstream instead of CFile". Those answers are boring asf

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about some settings I can only do a qualified guess.

E.g. depending on how you compile this, UNICODE or !UNICODE the CString behaves differently, i.e. maps to etiher CStringA or CStringW. The CString also behaves differently depending on the MFC version, in some cases there is a operator to implicit convert to a c string, in some not.

An ofstream normally expects a const char* as argument, so you may want to change it to

```
ofstream outfile(filename.GetBuffer(255));
```

in that case.

EDIT:

Did you check if you could open the file? from the above code it seems you assume success...

```
if ( outfile.is_open() )
...
```

Comment: CStringA will automatically convert to a const char* pointer, so there's no need to use GetBuffer. Microsoft's ofstream will take either a const char* or a const wchar_t* in the constructor, so either CString variant will work.

Comment: Yes as I said, it varies between the MFC versions in older version there was no automatic conversion so in order to be on the safe side(since I didn't know what version of MFC the OP was using) I gave the suggestion with GetBuffer